# "Previous" & "Next" submit Form, incrementing or decreasing a value between a very limited range

Tags: php, forms, post, range, addition

I am trying to work this out but I am unable, I need some help:
I am working on a form, with 2 inputs type submit: one increases +1, and the other one decreases -1, starting from zero (which is the bottom limit) to 5 (which is the top limit).

So, for starters the value is zero and I am supposed to not be able to decrease it, just increase it. And once I arrived to 5 I am also not be able to increase it more, just decrease it.

Obviously the limited range of 5 is an example, I need this value to be a variable. 
This form can be very useful for displaying items like files from a folder.
Any help is very appreciated.

```
<style>
.big_form{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.select_less{
    float: left;
}
.select_more{
    float: right;
}
.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['freak'])){
    if(isset($_POST['more'])){
        $current_value=$_POST['freak']+1;
        }else{
        $current_value=$_POST['freak']-1;
        }
    }else{
$current_value=0;   
}
echo("<div class='center'>". $current_value ."</div>");
echo("<br/>");
?>
<div class="big_form">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="freak" value="<?php echo($current_value);?>"/>
        <input class="select_less" type="submit" name="less" value="less"/>
        <input class="select_more" type="submit" name="more" value="more"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

PD. In this form I made here, there is not a limited range between 0 and 5.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I need a form as I stated: with a starting zero value, which I can add increments, of +1, and later, if I want, decreased -1.
Top limit: 5
bottom limit: 0

Comment: And you want us to just create it for you?

Comment: Just an orientation. It's done, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the value thru the currently used `$_POST` value and just add a checking if the value will be less than zero or greater than 5:

```
<?php
// simple initialization
$freak = 0;

// if action is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $freak = $_POST['freak'];
    $action = $_POST['submit'];
    if($action == 'less') {
        $freak = ($freak - 1 < 0) ? 0 : $freak - 1;
    } elseif($action == 'more') {
        $freak = ($freak + 1 > 5) ? 5 : $freak + 1;
    }

}

?>
<div class="big_form">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="freak" value="<?php echo $freak; ?>" /><br/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="less">Less</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="more">More</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could also use sessions, so that your values will persist. Then you can do the minus and plus. Simple example:

```
<?php
session_start();
// simple initialization
if(!isset($_SESSION['freak'])) {
    $_SESSION['freak'] = 0;
}

// if action is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $action = $_POST['submit'];
    if($action == 'less') {
        $_SESSION['freak'] = ($_SESSION['freak'] - 1 < 0) ? 0 : $_SESSION['freak'] - 1;
    } elseif($action == 'more') {
        $_SESSION['freak'] = ($_SESSION['freak'] + 1 > 5) ? 5 : $_SESSION['freak'] + 1;
    }

}

?>
<div class="big_form">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="freak" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['freak']; ?>" /><br/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="less">Less</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="more">More</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LdvDIA)

Comment: @dream333r sure no prob. im glad this helped